# Maven exec:java goal on a multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I'm trying to run `exec-maven-plugin`'s `exec:java` goal on a simple two-module project where one module depends on the other. So far I can't find a configuration that works. Here's a boiled-down test case:

```
+ exec-multi-module-test/
    + pom.xml
    + module1/
        + pom.xml
        + src/
            + main/
                + java/
                    + HelloPrinter.java
    + module2/
        + pom.xml
        + src/
            + main/
                + java/
                    + MyMain.java
```

Here's the parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mkscrg.sandbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-multi-module-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`module1`'s pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>exec-multi-module-test</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mkscrg.sandbox</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
</project>
```

`module2`'s pom:


4.0.0

```
    <parent>
        <artifactId>exec-multi-module-test</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mkscrg.sandbox</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mkscrg.sandbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This project compiles successfully from the top, but running `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=myMain` fails:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] exec-multi-module-test
[INFO] module1
[INFO] module2
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building exec-multi-module-test 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ exec-multi-module-test >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ exec-multi-module-test <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ exec-multi-module-test ---
[WARNING] 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyMain
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:285)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] exec-multi-module-test ............................ FAILURE [0.363s]
[INFO] module1 ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] module2 ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.566s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 18 14:11:54 PDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project exec-multi-module-test: An exception occured while executing the Java class. MyMain -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

What's the right way to configure this project to allow `exec:java` to see `MyMain`?

EDIT: Here's a gist if you'd like to try this yourself: https://gist.github.com/2950830

EDIT: Clarification: I know it's possible to `mvn install` and then either run `exec:java` from `module2`'s directory or use the `-pl` flag from the top. However, I'd like to avoid running `mvn install`. It shouldn't be necessary to modify my local repository in order to run this goal in a multi-module project. Just as `mvn compile` "just works" with a multi-module project, so should other goals/phases.

Comment: This seems to be common enough that [Maven 4 will allow this to just work](https://maarten.mulders.it/2020/11/whats-new-in-maven-4/#root-reactor-aware-subfolder-builds). Maven 4 is currently in alpha, so this can't be used yet. But out of curiosity, I cloned the current development version from the github repo, built it and tried it, and it does work.

Comment: `Maven 4 is currently in alpha` I have to say it's not released in any way currently. It is under development correct...

Comment: No chance that will ever work in maven: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-7527, my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73255826/executing-individual-maven-plugin-goals-in-multi-module-project

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Goals in a multi-module project, when run from the parent, will run against all modules. I don't think that's what you want.  You can try:

```
mvn exec:java -pl module2 -Dexec.mainClass=MyMain
```

That might work? More info:

- [Running a specific Maven plugin goal from the command line in a sub-module of a multi-module reactor project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459928/running-a-specific-maven-plugin-goal-from-the-command-line-in-a-sub-module-of-a/3460241#3460241)

However, I think it's more intuitive to change directory to the sub-module containing the executable before running it.

Comment: This (and `cd`ing to the submodule) only work if you've run `mvn install` from the top. Otherwise it fails because it can't find `module1` in any repository.

`mvn compile` successfully resolves the modules even though they're not installed in the local repo. I'm looking for a way to get that behavior with `mvn exec:java`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I added a clarification in the question.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to run exec:java without install unless the maven reactor is invoked.  Complicating the issue is that when run from the parent POM, there are no dependencies, so exec:java can't find the main class (much less any dependencies.)  And when run from the sub-module, the parent/sibling resolution doesn't take place. I tried a number of ideas, but the only that one that worked was @Raghuram 's answer to bind to a lifecycle goal.

Comment: @MikeCraig -- this answer doesn't work. Why did you accept it? I think Maven can't do this without "install". SBT can do this, but it has its own heap of issues.

Comment: typically you can add the flag `-am` to also make the dependent modules, but this causes the plugin to try to run within that module

Comment: Unfortunately, I was hoping that `{parent}/config` folder would be included in the classpath where property files are searched, but using this method, it is not. :-(

Comment: This answer is wrong. Only works if there is no dependencies between modules, what is not a typical scenario in multi-module context. Will cause "Could not resolve dependencies" error in all other cases.

Answer (score 13):

- You should bind the `exec-maven-plugin` to a maven lifecycle goal, say `verify`.
- Since you want the plugin to be executed only for `module`2, define the plugin configurations in the parent pom within `pluginManagement`.  Use the same only in `module 2`.
- Then run the following:

`mvn verify -Dexec.mainClass=MyMain`.

parent pom

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <phase>verify</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>java</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

module 2

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I verified this works. Cool! Would it be cleaner to use a special profile for configuring this goal only when running exec:java? Otherwise, the exec will be invoked on any activity that goes through the verify lifecycle.

Comment: @kaliatech. Yes indeed, based on the requirement.

Comment: @Raghuram - I tried this solution, and it works great for running the verify phase. However, when I try to run `mvn exec:java` maven throws an exception telling me that the parameter 'mainClass' is missing for the parent project (instead of only trying to find the mainclass for the child project). Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: for me this doesn't work. executing the module every time in the verify phase is not necessary in my case. i only need to run it when i manually want to start the application, not automatically every time when i'm compiling/packaging/installing/deploying.

Answer (score 6):

See this answer for a single-command alternative without `mvn install`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26448447/1235281

By using `skip` in the parent `pom.xml`, you can tell Maven to only run `exec:java` on a specific submodule.

GitHub:
https://github.com/Oduig/mavenfiddle

Comment: Sep. 2023, Maven 3 & 4 - still the only meaningful reference