# couldn't execute maven multi module project using exec-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, exec-maven-plugin, maven-exec-plugin

I've a multi module maven project [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/paranamer-maven-demo) .

The parent project has 3 modules common, with-paranamer, without-paranamer.

The with-paranamer and  without-paranamer modules are independent of each other and both are depend on common module.

In without-paranamer module I have added dependency to common module like [this](https://github.com/rajcspsg/paranamer-maven-demo/blob/master/without-paranamer/pom.xml#L15-L19).

Below is the structure of the project.

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── common
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├─ src
│      ├── main
│         ├─ java
│            ├── ParanamerUtil.java
│            ├── PersonV03.java
│            └── TestCaseClasses.java
│
├── with-paranamer
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├──src
│      ├── main
│         ├── java
│            └── ParanamerExample.java
|
└── without-paranamer
    ├── pom.xml
    ├─ src
       ├── main
          ├── java
              └── ParametersExample.java
```

I want to execute `ParametersExample`  class in without-paranamer module using exec-maven-plugin.
  So I added exec-maven-plugin under pluginManagement in parent pom.xml [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/paranamer-maven-demo/blob/master/pom.xml#L30-L50).
In without-paranamer module I have added plugin like [this](https://github.com/rajcspsg/paranamer-maven-demo/blob/master/without-paranamer/pom.xml#L23-L28).

I've followed the above instructions as mentioned in the stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091311/maven-execjava-goal-on-a-multi-module-project).

When I run `mvn verify` the command is successful.

But when I try riunning the command `mvn  exec:java  -Dexec.mainClass=ParametersExample -pl without-paranamer` I'm getting below error.

```
WARNING] The POM for paranamer-maven-demo:common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.189 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-07T17:23:07-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project without-paranamer: Could not resolve dependencies for project paranamer-maven-demo:without-paranamer:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact paranamer-maven-demo:common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

How can I make my program run successful using the exec-maven-plugin.

Comment: you're having a dependency problem - the re is no such artifact: paranamer-maven-demo:common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT. Show your pom.xml for all modules and project

Comment: link to the code repository is https://github.com/rajcspsg/paranamer-maven-demo. It is also in the first line of this question. Also paranamer-maven-demo:common:jar is submodule of the parent project. I've added dependency as well.

Comment: you should put the pom.xml fragment here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`without-paranamer` module has a dependency on `paranamer-maven-demo.common.1.0-SNAPSHOT`, but where can it finds it? Most obvious answer: in local repository. But its not there, unless you install it (also, you have to install pom of parent project).

`mvn -N clean install` - installs parent pom.( `-N` stands for `non recursive`, which means goals will be executed only for parent project, and not for child modules).

`mvn -pl common  clean install` - installs `common` module.

Now, calling `exec:java` will be successful (but didn't print any output, because of `<skip>true</skip>` in plugin management configuration)

Comment: I could only make it work with `mvn clean install` without the `-N` flag. Will there be problems if you install all the modules? And if yes, am I right to assume it's the ones being "depended" on that needs installing? As of now, I'm happily ignorant in don't-fix-it-if-it aint broke-land.