# Is it possible to load Spring-Boot properties from config folder within parent module of a Maven multi-module project?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-3, multi-module

Is it possible to load multiple Spring-Boot .yml config files from a `config` folder within parent module of a multi-module project?

So, structure looks like this:

```
parent-module/
  pom.xml
  config/
    application-prd.yml
    application-dev.yml
  module1
    pom.xml
    src/main/resources/
      logback-spring.xml
      bootstrap.yml
```

Is this possible?   How can it be done?

So, if I execute from root folder of multi-module project, I would use this command:

```
mvn -pl module1 spring-boot:run
   OR
mvn spring-boot:run
```

And I would hope that the `config` folder would be included in the classpath?    I am trying to do this but not getting it to work.  Am I missing something?

We know this to be true: `Child POMs inherit properties, dependencies, and plugin configurations from the parent.`  But shouldn't that mean that `{parent}/config/application.yml` is in the classpath already?

Example project to use for proving: https://github.com/djangofan/spring-boot-maven-multi-module-example . Clone it and modify if you think you can solve it.

Comment: what if you copy the files from `parent` to `module1` using `maven-resources-plugin` at `package` phase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write code. You can use Exec Maven Plugin for this. Add the plugin to the parent module:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>PACKAGE.MODULE_MAIN_CLASS</mainClass>
        <arguments>
          <argument>--spring.profiles.active=dev</argument>
        </arguments>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

then run `mvn install` once and then `mvn exec` whenever you want to start the application.

```
mvn exec:java -pl module1
```

For more on Maven goals in a multi-module project, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11091569/512667 .

Another way to configure this is like so, which requires the `workingDirectory` arg:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.example.Application</mainClass>
        <workingDirectory>${maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory}</workingDirectory>
        <arguments>
            <argument>--spring.profiles.active=dev</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In this case, execute:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -pl module1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it and it did not work.  Here is the branch where I tried it:  https://github.com/djangofan/spring-boot-maven-multi-module-example/blob/d7f537f2bd4937890fb1ee4c30e9f57437edccef/spring-boot-module/pom.xml#L79-L86

Comment: @djangofan The github URL is not accessible

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the url. Still getting used to Github defaulting to private.

Comment: Alright, so I checked out your branch and did mvn install > mvn exec:java -pl spring-boot-module and it works. I can call your GET /all and I can see 2 JSON objects. Is this what you expect?

Comment: It just looks like it works.   The red-herring is that it starts on the wrong port: 8080 .  It's not actually reading the properties file.

Comment: my bad, just append the profile argument to the mvn command:  mvn exec:java -pl spring-boot-module -Dspring.profiles.active=dev

Comment: Yep, that worked.    I think I will award  you the bounty.  Thank you.     Also, the spring "default profile" can be put in a properties file instead of on command line, making the execution simpler.     I would rather use spring-boot-maven-plugin but it is nice to know this solution works.

Comment: I updated your answer.   I hope you don't mind.   Just added more info.

Comment: Not at all, glad you found the answer you were looking for

Comment: Yep, you helped me discover the typo in my initial POC.  I just needed that `workingDirectory` parameter to `maven-spring-boot-plugin`.  Thanks for being my rubber ducky and showing me a 2nd way to do it.

Comment: no problems. Doesn't your rubber ducky deserve your promised bounty? ;-)

Comment: I'm not totally sure how bounty gets auto-rewarded.   If I could just award you myself I would be I think we were in the after bounty expiration period.  I'm pretty sure you should have got at least half of it.

Comment: Alright, I just thought you forgot to do it. No problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Maven changes the working directory to the module's directory when you use the `-pl`. So it is no longer the root which has the `config/` dir.

Either you can refactor your maven multi-module setup to a way that you can package the common `application.yml` files and than use them. I wouldn't recommend that as it has many pitfalls.

Probably easier to use the `--spring.config-location`

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

I can not test it at the moment but if it doesn't work you can always try the `-Dspring.config.location` or the `SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` environment variable.

Comment: Looking for an answer that doesn't require overriding the classpath in any way.   Simplest possible command line.   I've seen it done before, but I just don't remember how they did it.

Comment: Defining an environment variable or specifying system variable according my answer does not override classpath.

Comment: My point is that I believe there is a way to do this without specifying spring.config.location  on command line.   I know because I have seen it work; I just don't know the specifics.   I'll work on making a Github example project and if I can solve it on my own, ill share.

Comment: The question could be where did you seen that working. Afaik intelij idea does that by default.

Comment: Discovered that passing `workingDirectory` arg to `spring-boot-maven-plugin` fixed my issue.   Spring now auto-scans the `/config` folder from where I set working directory.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled as to why that would be simpler than just setting spring config location, which is pretty much the standard way of doing it @djangofan

Answer (score 1):

I found a [customized way of doing it](https://github.com/djangofan/spring-boot-maven-multi-module-example/blob/54d82001cdbe82eefbf80b249d4f4bbb007c103e/spring-boot-module/src/main/java/com/example/Application.java#L35-L47), which I still consider to be a hack, as you can see below, but I am still looking for an actual answer to my question, if it exists.

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static String DEV_PROPS = "application-dev.properties";
    private static String PRD_PROPS = "application-prd.properties";
    private static String DEFAULT_PROPS = "application.properties";

    private static Path CONFIG = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"))
            .resolve(Paths.get(".."))
            .resolve("config");

    private static final String EXT_CONFIG_DIR = CONFIG.toString() + File.separator;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Resource[] resources = new Resource[] {
                        new FileSystemResource(EXT_CONFIG_DIR + PRD_PROPS),
                        new FileSystemResource(EXT_CONFIG_DIR + DEV_PROPS),
                        new ClassPathResource(DEFAULT_PROPS)
                };
        log.info("Properties: " + Arrays.deepToString(resources));
        properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        properties.setLocations(resources);
        return properties;
    }

}
```

The problem with this method, is that configuration has to be changed to support additional `environment profile names`.