# Executing spring-boot:run when not inheriting from spring-boot-starter-parent

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I have a spring-boot maven project, which cannot have `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a parent due to organizational restrictions. I came across [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317006/spring-boot-parent-pom-when-you-already-have-a-parent-pom/21318359#21318359) which helped me with compiling, testing and packaging an executable jar.

However when I try to execute `spring-boot:run` i receive the following error:

```
No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories
```

The following comment in the answer seems to point to away to fix this:

```
The code snippet above is sufficient to get the dependency management features. If you want plugins (like spring-boot:run) you need to confute those separately. You can copy paste from the Boot parent if you want
```

However after adding the proposed section to my pom file I still get the same error. My pom files can be found below:

Parent pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>group.id.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo_artifact</artifactId>
    <version>version_01</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>2.2.1</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <modules>
        <module>module_01</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <!--compilerArgument>-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1</compilerArgument-->
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Child pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <ing.continuous-delivery.version>00.04.04</ing.continuous-delivery.version>
        <maven.assembly.version>2.3</maven.assembly.version> 
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>group.id.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo_artifact</artifactId>
        <version>version_01</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>group.id.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>${project.parent.artifactId}_app</artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>

     <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- tag::spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::spring -->

        <!-- tag::web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::web -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should run `spring-boot:run` from inside child module folder

Comment: Yes that would work, but is there a way to run it from the parent directory? Gradle has similar functionality

Comment: I am not aware of such a possibility in maven.

Comment: Using `mvn spring-boot:run -pl module_01` should be an option

Comment: @Tome good catch!

Comment: @Tome works like a charm! However I wonder if there's a way to do it without referencing the module from the CLI. Is there a way to create a target in the parent pom which maps to the the one in the child?

Comment: @jonatzin, have a look at the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459928/running-a-specific-maven-plugin-goal-from-the-command-line-in-a-sub-module-of-a