# Quarkus project once covered to mutli-module form got 404 when hit the existing endpoints

Tags: quarkus

**quarkus.version**:1.0.1.Final

Used to have working `quarkus` web project with rest-easy end-points.

Converted it to multi-module one.

Still use `maven`.

This way:

```
 my-project-service
   - my-project-api
     - data-api-object.java
     - pom.xml // dep on `quarkus-core` as `provided`
   - my-project-backend
     - pom.xml  + depends on my-project-api
   - pom.xml // managed dependencies defined
```

Similar to [this example](https://github.com/Charlesleonius/Quarkus-Multi-Module), actually.

All compiles and runs.

```
./mvnw compile quarkus:dev
```

I see log:

```
- [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 1.0.1.Final started in 1.595s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
- [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, infinispan-client, jaeger, narayana-jta, reactive-pg-client, rest-client, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-fault-tolerance, smallrye-health, smallrye-metrics, smallrye-openapi, smallrye-opentracing, swagger-ui, vertx]
```

But when I hit once worked end-point:

http://localhost:8080/my-project-service/stuff

I got: `404`

If I check my health-check url:
http://localhost:8080/my-project-service/health/ready

In my-project-backend / ... / resources/application.properties

```
quarkus.application.name=my-project-service
quarkus.http.root-path=/my-project-service
```

so I actually have to call http://localhost:8080/my-project-service/. This has has not been changed.

I guess, the call never reached the app.

**Q:** What could be the problem?

**UPDATE:**

I got that null-pointer ex when run.

FYI: may /src/main/etc folders is empty - no sources in parent pom project (  pom).

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.normalizeAndCheck(UnixPath.java:77)
```

I did clean /target folder etc... did not help.

I can reach the http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/ - it works but empty. once worked http://localhost:8080/my-project-service/swagger-ui/ get 404 as well.

(maybe related to this [fix](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/commit/bc1ffba31f9979b4b60f2bcb6a122a6298649744))

I tried to move resources/application.properties (not sure where it should be) to my root project. no effect.

P.S.
 I converted all (also) to `Gralde`. Same issue.

**UPDATE 2:**

- switched to latest (now 1.1.0.CR1) version
- now I see some new exceptions:
  -`Failed to start Quarkus: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple matching properties for name "datasource.url"` even though I have one per env, only one for dev: %dev.quarkus.datasource.url

  I guess it is just a new bug. Rolling back where I was.

**UPDATE3:**
 If I compile native, application works/reacts on rest requests. Seems it is only about dev (and probably hot reload thing).

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6168

Answer (score 0):

So far, (based on [git thread](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6170)) to make it work:

1. from the parent folder:

> ./mvnw clean install -DskipTests

, so it would resolve/register all deps/artifacts

2. Then compile/run it from the child one, the one that is responsible for running the app, the back-end.

> cd my-project-backend
>
> mvn compile quarkus:dev

**Only** my-project-backend should contain the `<build>..<plugin> <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>` not the parent one.

---

About the version: to use the `1.1.0.CR`1+ one,
 make sure we do not have have both of those deps: `quarkus-agroal` and the `quarkus-reactive-pg-client` dependencies.

Both of them define the `quarkus.datasource.url` that's why.. I leave only the `quarkus-reactive-pg-client` one.

---

Not sure if it should be this way. Or run from the parent, ultimately. TBD.

And native [seems does not work](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6168#issuecomment-565730904). TBD.

Answer (score 0):

while trying it I hit this issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6275

Did you hit this issue as well with the latest Quarkus version?